# HTML automatic column width seems to ignore text wrapping

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm struggling to understand why my the columns in a number of tables I've created are being set to the width they are.

The tables are fixed width (width:45% in CSS), have similar length cell content and with one exception the same headings. My understanding is that it is the heading which governs column width. What I don't understand is that it appears to ignore wrapping.

The first table contains:

```
<th>column1</th>
<th>longerword</th>
<th>column3</th>
```

and the second table:

```
<th>column1</th>
<th>short word</th>
<th>column3</th>
```

"short word" wraps and so is effectively shorter than "longerword" but the column is much wider which seems illogical and wastes space.

Is there any way to use the wrapped text width to set the column width?

Other than the width of the table and some padding for  and  I have no formatting which would affect size/position/spacing

Answer (score 0):

If the column  width is less then the word length, then by default the words will wrap. Your easiest solution would be to use css and force a no wrap:

```
<th style="white-space: nowrap;">short word</th>
```

or

```
<style> th {white-space: nowrap;} </style>
```

Comment: Thanks but the wrapping isn't the problem. The word wrap is needed for the column width suitable for the contents of the table. What I would like to change is the column width setting so that it is calculated based on the wrapped text (rather than fixed). It looks as if it's set on unwrapped content.